# VBA imposible abrir un documento de word desde excel

Tags: excel, vba

Estoy intentando abrir un archivo Word desde una macro de Excel para actualizar unas tablas vinculadas. El programa se me para siempre en la linea que abre el fichero word. He intentado  cambiar la variable docObj para que sea de tipo Object en lugar de Word.Document, obteniendo el mismo problema. Tambien he intentado abrir la aplicacion Word con createObject y con getObject, según he visto en muchos ejemplos, pero nada. He intentado revisando la configuracion de Excel y Word activando todos los permisos a las macros, etc

```
Private Sub Document_Open()

Dim nFile As String
Dim nFile2 As String

Dim forma As Word.InlineShape
Dim etiq As String
Dim etiq2 As String
Dim etiq3 As String
Dim hoja As String
Dim nombreRango As String

Dim rango As Word.Range
Dim wordObj As Word.Application
Dim docObj As Word.Document

Dim excelRango As Excel.Range

nFile = ThisWorkbook.Name
nFile2 = Mid(nFile, 1, Len(nFile) - 5)
nombreword = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & nFile2 & ".docm"

Dim nFormas As Integer

Set wordObj = New Word.Application
wordObj.Visible = True
Set docObj = wordObj.Documents.Open(Filename:=nombreword)
```

El fragmento de codigo intenta abrir un documento word que tenga el mismo nombre que el archivo Excel en el que se encuentra alojada la macro. En la ultima linea se obtiene siempre el error 435: el objeto no admite esa propiedad o metodo
Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de variable es `nombreword` ? Depura tu código con F8 y mira paso a paso lo que sucede.

Comment: Por experiencia, antes de nada, tienes que revisar que las instancias que abres en word, sean cerradas, ya que sino te va a dar mil problemas. Implementa un control de errores:
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

' Tu código aquí

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
   If Not docObj Is Nothing Then
        docObj.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
        Set docObj = Nothing
    End If

    If Not wordObj Is Nothing Then
        wordObj.Quit
        Set wordObj = Nothing
    End If
    MsgBox "Se produjo un error: " & Err.Description, vbCritical
End Sub

Comment: Y antes de ejecutar las pruebas, CONTROL-ALT-SUB tareas y revisa no tener un winword en Procesos...

Comment: Y mejor es que  el wordObj.Visible = True este despues de abrir el documento. 
Set docObj = wordObj.Documents.Open(Filename:=nombreword)
wordObj.Visible = True
Ya que cuando haces visible la aplicación Word antes de abrir el documento, el usuario verá la aplicación Word abrirse y luego cargar el documento, lo que puede llevar algún tiempo dependiendo del tamaño del documento y la velocidad del sistema. Esto puede dar la impresión de que la macro es lenta o está funcionando mal.

Comment: Y como dice Esei te falta definir el nombre del archivo que quieres abrir>
Dim nombreword As String
nombreword = "C:\ruta\del\archivo\MiWord.docm"

Answer (score 0):

Perdonandme que hace tiempo que no me paso por aqui
Se soluciono con una reinstalacion de Office
Muchas gracias, pcandido y compañia